# Installing latest Java 8. Ubuntu 14.04. (Need Guide)

Tags: 14.04, java

I need Java to log into my bank (passwords etc)

http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp  Recommended Version 8 Update 25

I am very new to Linux/Ubuntu. But i did follow a guide to use Terminal to download and installing skype.

Could anyone please make a Guide for the same regarding installing Java on my laptop!?

I do not have any version of java previously installed. I can only find guides for updating previos java..

All in all, i need someone to explain the steps to get JAVA installed on my 14.04.

I belive i need latest working java, because for security usage, passwords in my bank.

I have Norwegian language on my pc, will change to English if needed in Terminal.
(Need a guide to set English language also lol. if needed)

Any help, appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing `icedtea-7-plugin` should resolve this for you. It will install what basically amounts to an open source version of Java 7 along with the icedtea-7-plugin package which is a web browser plugin for accessing this version of Java.

Simply run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

This method will ensure that you automatically receive Java-related security updates whenever your system updates through apt-get (Update Manager is basically just a GUI front-end for apt-get, by the way).

After this, simply restart your browser and enjoy your new Java functionality.

Note 1: According to [this website](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/IcedTea-Web#Plugin), the icedtea plugin should work with Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, and Midori, and it may also work fine with other browsers as well.

Note 2: There is currently no supported icedtea plugin for java 8. See this IcedTea wiki page for reference: 
[IcedTea Main Page](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Language side note: If the command I gave you does not work due to the language difference, let me know so that I can work on determining the best way for you to go about installing the package.

Comment: I did this now and it installed. But does not show up in firefox, i have restartetd computer to check also. No extentions or program/apps..   The dnb.no starts loading after i have entered my personal number. But says i have not installed java..

Comment: Open Firefox's "Add-ons" menu, navigate to "Plugins", and see if Icedtea plugin shows up in that list. If it does, ensure that it is set to "ask to activate" or if "ask to activate" isn't working, set to "always activate".

Comment: Icedtea did not get installed by your command line. had to go to software center and do it. I have set it to allways active, but still dosent work, now the java window on the sites load, but it just gives me error and say something was typed wrong, so i guess this is not secure enough for my bank or something.

Comment: Please Post a new one with another option to install java 8.

Comment: EDIT: it can be some sort of password trouble, will contact my bank and come back to this.

Comment: I would recommend that. Also, I had the dependencies backwards. Editing to reflect this.

Comment: Sadly nothing worked, i have tried every possible solution i could find, also reinstalled linux 5 times while trying.. So for bank i have to use windows.